# Set timeout on an FTP Connect in Java

Tags: java, ftp

Im trying to set a timeout on an FTP *Connect* using com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient but for some reason can't get it to work.

This is my code:

```
public boolean testFtpDetails(String path) {
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.setRemoteHost("210.160.1.100");
        ftp.setTimeout(3000);
        ftp.connect();

        ftp.login("test", "test");

        success = ftp.connected();

        if (success && path != null) {
            ftp.chdir(path);
        }

        ftp.quit();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {            
    } catch (IOException e) {            
    } catch (FTPException e) {
}
```

So after 3 seconds of trying to execute ftp.connect() I would expect it to timeout. However this does not happen and it takes around 15 seconds to timeout. Is there a way to change this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

the setTimeout method is documented as:

```
Set the SO_TIMEOUT in milliseconds on the underlying socket.
```

In this way it only affects the low level socket operations. The questions would be - what kind of timeout are you expecting to happen?

On connect ? During transfer? On idle?

If you connect to e.g. an unknown host you will also have DNS lookup taking most of the time before the timeout is even considered.

Comment: Basically the user presses a 'Test Connection' button and nothing happens for 20 seconds whilst it tries to connect. I wanted to get a response within a few seconds. If it doesnt respond in this time then just fail.